# How do I keep my python backend scripts running forever on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, service, backend

I want to keep my Python scripts running forever on Windows Server 2012.

I tried using MS Windows Task Scheduler, but it keeps creating new instances of the script every time and hence, fills my memory. Currently I run my scripts through command prompt and keep them minimized, and I never log out from the Server.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create to create a service then use Scheduled Tasks to control it.

Comment: Hi, I'll try this and let you know. In case if I restart my server, will this run on startup? Or do I need to manually run this service again?

Comment: There should be a setting in there that allows you to start on boot.